# Vue.js : passing item as parameter to computed prop in v-for, returning child array sorted ?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

Have been googling around for quite a while to figure out how to do this..

I have a list of "Intents", which each of them got a list of "Entities", presented in a nested v-for.

Intents are already computed, but i need to also sort the "Entities" list on the fly, so therefore i thought that making that list also computed..

**Error :**

```
**TypeError: _vm.entityList is not a function**
```

**This is my current approach :**

```js
< script >
  import uniq from 'lodash/uniq'
import orderby from 'lodash/orderby'
import Util from "@/components/util.js"

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      // ....
    }
  },
  computed: {
    nluData() {
      return orderby(this.$store.getters.nlujson.filter(item => {
        return item.intent.toLowerCase() === this.selectedIntent
      }), ['intent', 'text'], ['asc', 'asc'])
    },
    entityList(item) {
      return orderby(item.entities, ['entity', 'value'], ['asc', 'asc'])
    },
  },
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch('getNluJson')
  },
  methods: {
    // ......    
  }


  </script>
```

```html
// parent structure
<div v-for="(item, key, index) in nluData">
  // displaying nluData content through item.mydata // child structure
  <div v-for="ent in entityList(item)">
    // displaying entities data through computed prop. // item.entities is the array
  </div>
</div>

{
   "id": "J4a9dGEBFtvEmO3Beq31",
   "text": "This is Intent 1",
   "intent": "shelf_life",
   "entities": [
    {
     "start": "33",
     "end": "44",
     "value": "fridge",
     "entity": "ingredient_placement"
    },
    {
     "start": "10",
     "end": "20",
     "value": "duration",
     "entity": "shelf_life"
    },
    {
     "start": "25",
     "end": "30",
     "value": "spareribs",
     "entity": "ingredient"
    }
   ]
  },
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A computed property don't get any params. In your case, the prop `entityList()` must be a method :

```
methods : {
    entityList(item) {
      return orderby(item.entities, ['entity', 'value'], ['asc', 'asc'])
    },
},
```

> https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html

Answer (score 21):

You can pass parameters to a computed property with an anonymous function like so:

```
computed: {
  entityList() {
    return (item) =>
      orderby(item.entities, ['entity', 'value'], ['asc', 'asc']);
    },
  },
```